# Connecting An <a> tag to a ViewController mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know this is probably straight forward, but this isnt working for me, I want to simply connect this to trigger a viewController when I click it. When I create a controller and a view and click it it throws a 404 and the code never hits the controller.

```
 <div><a href="../Admin/AdminReports.aspx"> All Accounts In the System</a></div>
```

Comment: judging by your recent questions, you don't seem to have a good grasp on ASP.NET MVC and how it's different from WebForms. Start with the tutorials here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc-part1

Comment: @yada, that has nothing to do with the question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
<a href='<%= Url.Action("Controller", "Action") %>'>Text</a>
```

where

Controller = Your controller name.
Action = Your action method.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably follow few tutorials for mvc. Links are by default using System.Web.Routing magic (if you have default template, look into global.asax). Default url looks like `/controller/action/id` where id is optional, action defaulted to *Index* and controller defaulted to *Home*. For link construction in views use these helper methods:

```
@Html.ActionLink("All accounts in the system", "AdminReports", "Admin");
```

or

```
<a href="@Url.Action("AdminReports", "Admin")">All accounts in the system</a>
```

The link should look like `/Admin/AdminReports` with default settings.